# I am trying to create a function with arguments and call it from another function in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my code but verifyUser won't work I don't know why that won't work

```
errorLog(props){
    if (props.errors) {
        return (
            <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <p>{props.message}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }else{
        return null
    }
}

verifyUser(){
    const username = this.refs.username.value;
    const password = this.refs.password.value;

    if(!username || !password) {
       // this.setState({error: true})

        this.errorLog({errors:true})

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? What do you see in the console?

Comment: this is what i get .  Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined

Comment: This code looks good, are you sure you are not calling `this.errorLog` somewhere else?

Comment: try printing `props` just before the if statement.  looking at the code, there should not be an issue, unless there is another call that doesn't come from `verifyUser`.

Comment: You are returning your alert div but I don't see you doing anything with it in the verifyUser function. If you want this to show up you would need it to be in the render function of your component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an alert to appear when some error happens in verification you need your html to end up in the render function.

```
class Alert extends React.Component {
  errorLog(errObj) {
    if (errObj.errors)
      return <div>ALERT</div>;
  }

  verifyUser() {
    // ... do some verification

    const err = this.errorLog({ errors: true });

    return err;
  }

  render() {
    const err = this.verifyUser();
    return err;
  }
}
```

Here is a JSBin to show this in action:

http://jsbin.com/rakerif/edit?html,js,output